# Service 'MongoDB Server' (MongoDB) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services

Tags: mongodb

I install Mongodb 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2 server, but I cannot start the service. Looking at the system log there are error as below

```
Product: MongoDB 4.0.0 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit) -- Error 1920. Service 'MongoDB Server' (MongoDB) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

and

```
Faulting application name: mongod.exe, version: 4.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b2c1668
Faulting module name: i-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x5450559e
Exception code: 0xc0000135
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ec5a0
Faulting process id: 0x25f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4284df2a95fad
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe
Faulting module path: i-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
Report Id: 3056be2a-9441-11e8-80bb-d0946652c910
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Do you have any hint to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you install using the .msi package?

Comment: yes, I used the .msi. Try to add visual c++ redistributable as some suggestion, but there is no result!

Comment: Try installing windows patch KB2999226-x64

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've never used MongoDB before and I'm not sure what to do about it. I'm logged in as an administrator and accepting all defaults (I had wondered if it was down to my changing the default data and log dirs but apparently not). Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, [guide to install MongoDB on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), they have mentioned to have the updated windows or at least have [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) update for Windows 2012 Server and Windows 10 to provide universal C runtime support for Windows.

They have another required update for Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 also.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I install MongoDB on WIndows 7. The issue was resolved when I install newest updates fow Windows 7.